# Protect PC817 Optocoupler Anode from High Voltage

Tags: opto-isolator

Voltage at `IN3` will vary from 10V to 28V, How can I protect the optocoupler from getting damaged due to high voltage.

What is the maximum voltage and Minimum voltage should be given at anode (Pin 1) to sense LOW properly on GPIO.

Is there any external pull up needed at Pin 4 connected to GPIO of MCU.?

**EDIT :**

I am doing few calculations based on the comments, let me know if they are right

First of all the Optocoupler forward voltage is 1.2V and the maximum forward current for LED is 60mA.

```
The value for resistor R13 should be 

We will take LED current as 10mA

R = (Vin - Vf)/I

R = (12-1.2)/0.01

R = 1080 ohm ~ 1K resistance

If Voltage is increased upto 28V,

I = (28-1.2)/1000 
  = 26mA
```

This is well below the maximum LED current i.e 60mA. So there should be no issue with the high voltage and the 1K resistor is fine.

Now coming to collector load resistor value which is not mentioned in the image,

```
in data sheet the Vce saturation voltage is 0.1~0.2V

if Load Resistor is 10K
Ic = (Vcc-Vce)/R
  = (5-0.1)/10000
  = 0.49 mA
```

This value is also well below the maximum collector current which is 50mA.

So I think based on above calculation, **Input resistor of 1K will work fine and collector Load resistor has to be added of value 10K.**

Comments?

[image]

Comment: Did you read the datasheet?? http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/73758.pdf

Comment: I read but unable to understand, as there are many specs mentioned. Which one to look?

Comment: why common gnd .. that defeats isolation.. like any OC logic pullup and min max current *CTR min/max defines margin with Vc= Vcc-IcRc thus indeterminate without Rc.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: basic current gain margin and input voltage margin with ohms law

Comment: Vce(sat ) with 20:1 Ib/Ic ratio is gauranteed

Comment: @LearnerLearner: Tony is trying to say a few things: (1) Usually opto-isolators are used to provide complete isolation between one circuit and another. You have both sides sharing a common ground, therefore they're not isolated, therefore why do you need the opto-isolator? (2) Opto-isolators have a current transfer ratio. e.g., At 5 mA of LED current you can get a maximum transistor collector current. Since we don't know your collector resistor \$ R_C \$ we can't finish the calculations.

Comment: (3) "Margin" is a safety factor after you've done your calculations. e.g., If 5 mA should work on the input then set it to 7 or 8 mA for safety and deterioration of the LED over time.

Comment: The important thing in transistors is Ic/Ib=10 to 20 for robust switches but due to coupling efficiencies in simple cheap optos Ic/Ib = 0.05 to 0.1  Then your compute the R values needed on each side depending on Vcc or Vdd and Vf=1.1V

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: You contribute a lot to the site but I think that you go over the head of the OPs quite often using acronyms, initialisations and electronic concepts that the users may not have come across. An extra few moments writing complete English sentences (subject - verb - object) would help too. This is just friendly feedback.

Comment: 1) protection needed is to prevent catastrophic failure from reversed polarity on input voltage. ( sometimes a reverse diode  across input diode is added to prevent field connection failures  but normally not necessary)  Then the Absolute MAX specs MUST never be exceeded, but recommended levels may be adjusted. e.g. I(in) may be as low as 1 mA thus R13 could be 10k but then if output is 3.3V with 100k pullup Ic = 30uA so Ic/Ib= 30u/1mA*100%< 5 to 10% so that works but rise time now with 30~250pF becomes longer with 100k pullup.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I understand what you are saying, I have done calculation based on your comments. Please check.

Comment: @Transistor I have edited my answer with few calculations please check.

Comment: The optocoupler's Ib is irrelevant; the CTR specifies Ic/ILED directly.

Answer (score 4):

Like a 'normal' LED, the LED of an optocoupler is not controlled by voltage but by current.

With the 1 kΩ resistor as shown, and with a LED forward voltage of about 1 V, the current through the LED would be between approximately 9 mA and 27 mA; the absolute maximum rating of the PC817 is 50 mA, so this would still be allowed.

However, that's still a lot of current, and might load the output connected to IN3 too much. Consider increasing R13 to 2.2 kΩ or 4.7 kΩ.
(It would also be possible to replace R13 with a constant current source.)

You need a pull-up resistor at pin 4. This can be either an external one, or an internal one in the µC.
The value of the pull-up is determined by the CTR of the optocoupler; in the worst case, this is 50 % at the specified input current of 5 mA, and less at other LED currents. So assuming that less than 1 mA comes through the optocoupler's output, and that the µC runs at 5 V, the pull-up should be at least 10 kΩ.

Comment: Can you check my calculation based on your response as well as  based on response in the comment section.

Comment: These calculations look OK.